# KivyMD: Widget Text is not updating no matter how it is tried

Tags: kivy, kivymd

first off I'm only learning Python and Kivy for a very short time, so that explains why the code surely looks not well structured to you. I am open to suggestions, but I'm actually here with a concrete problem in Kivy/KivyMD.

Also I'm sure you think this problem is common and I shouldn't make an extra post. I have searched a lot, but if you can reference a article that actually answers my question, I'll be grateful for that too.

I want to Update the Planlist - plan1 text with whatever the user enters into the Input. The groundwork is there, and the StingProperty does actively change to the UserInput as intended. However, neither the test-label in Planlist, nor the actual listitem update the text. Neither putting the actual string property as text in kv nor changing the text from the on on_text_validate function does the trick. What do i have to do differently here?

py:
'''

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList

class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    my_screen_manager = ObjectProperty()

class ScreenOverview(Screen):
    my_screen_manager = MyScreenManager()


class ScreenPlan1(Screen):
    pass


class Content(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.planlist = Planlist()
        self.MainApp = MainApp()
        self.cdialog = MainApp().dialog


class Planlist(MDList):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.text_input_str = StringProperty("")
        # self.text_input_str = "plan-unmodifiziert"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class MainApp(MDApp):
    dialog = None
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.plan1 = None
        self.planlist = Planlist()
        self.root = RootWidget()

        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"
        return Builder.load_file("fit_app.kv")

    def show_confirmation_dialog(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                title="Namenseingabe:",
                type="custom",
                content_cls=Content(),
                buttons=[
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="CANCEL", text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                        on_release=self.dialog_close
                    ),
                ],
                md_bg_color=(.38, .38, .38, 1)
            )
        self.dialog.open()

    def dialog_close(self, *args):
        self.dialog.dismiss(force=True)

    def on_text_validate(self, widget):
        self.planlist.text_input_str = widget.text
        print(self.planlist.text_input_str)
        print(widget.text)
        self.planlist.ids.plan1.text = widget.text

MainApp().run()
```

'''

kv:
'''

```
RootWidget:
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDToolbar:
        title: "FitApp"
        md_bg_color: .2,.2,.2,1
        specific_text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1

    MDBottomNavigation:
        # panel_color: .2, .2, .2, 1

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: "nav1"
            text: "Dashboard"
            icon: "desktop-mac-dashboard"

            MDLabel:
                text: "Python"
                halign: "center"

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: "nav2"
            text: "Workout"
            icon: "dumbbell"

            MyScreenManager:

                Screen:
                    name: "screen_overview"

                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: "vertical"
                        MDBoxLayout:
                            size_hint: 1, .2
                            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
                            MDLabel:
                                text: "Neuer Trainingsplan"
                                pos_hint: {"center_x":1, "top":1}
                                text_size: self.size
                                halign: 'left'
                                valign: 'top'
                                padding: "30dp", "30dp"

                            MDIconButton:
                                icon: "plus"
                                pos_hint: {"center_x":1, "center_y":.92}
                                # valign: "top"
                                on_release: app.show_confirmation_dialog()

                    Planlist:


                Screen:
                    name: "plan1"

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Screen"
                        halign: "center"
                    Button:
                        text: "change"
                        on_press:
                            screen_manager.current = 'overview'



        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: "nav3"
            text: "History"
            icon: "history"

            MDLabel:
                text: "Cobra"
                halign: "center"
<Content>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    spacing: "12dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "100dp"

    MDTextField:
        id: plan_name
        hint_text: "Planname"
        on_text_validate: root.MainApp.on_text_validate(self)


    MDFlatButton:
        text: "OK"
        size: "70dp", "30dp"      # size_hint MDFlatButton buggy?
        pos_hint: {"right": 1}
        on_release:
            root.MainApp.on_text_validate(plan_name)


<MyScreenManager>:
    id: screen_manager

    
<Planlist>:
    OneLineListItem:
        id: plan1
        text: "plan-unmodifiziert1"
        on_press: screen_manager.current = "plan1"
        Label:
            text: str(root.text_input_str)
    OneLineListItem:
        text: "plan-unmodifiziert2"
        on_press: screen_manager.current = "plan1"
    OneLineListItem:
        text: "plan-unmodifiziert3"
        on_press: screen_manager.current = "plan1"
```

'''

On a sidenote: The on_press commands of the MDlist items are not actually working as the code is structured right now. Im still struggling with communication between widgets from different places. Some hints on how to get that working would be a bonus, but I will try around with that after solving the problem mentioned above anyway.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Canot follow your code logic, but one error in your `Planlist` class is your attempted use of `StringProperty`. Properties should be defined within a widget class but outside of any method. Like this:

```
class Planlist(MDList):
    text_input_str = StringProperty("")

    # def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    #     self.text_input_str = StringProperty("")
    #     # self.text_input_str = "plan-unmodifiziert"
    #     super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure what your code is about : ((( But I think I get what you mean ( ? ) like when you inherit with the `MDApp` instead of `App` from `kivy.app.App` the widgets are not updated. I face this issue when I try to implement `kivymd` stuff to "normal kivy thing". My solution as follow :

- you have a main / base class for layout ( GUI ) --> `class Main(Widget)`
- and you got a method to update those widgets in the base class ( in `Main()` )
- in app class ( inherit with `MDApp` ) : inside the emethod `build` : name a variable with value = `Main()`
- use `kivy.clock.Clock.schedule_interval` to call the update method in `Main()` to update

sth like this :

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker
from kivy.clock import Clock

kv_file = """
#:kivy 2.0.0

<Main>:
    
    Label:
        id: my_label
        text: "a label here"
        font_size: 25
    
    MDRaisedButton:
        id: my_raised_button
        text: "this is a md raised button"
        font_size: 25
        center: root.center
"""
kivy.lang.Builder.load_string(kv_file)


class Main(Widget):  # base class , I just name it Main , lol
    num = 0
    
    def update(self, dt):  # method to update widgets
        self.ids.my_raised_button.center = self.center
        
        self.ids.my_label.text = str(self.num)
        self.num += 1


class MyKivyMDApp(MDApp):  # app class ( inherit with MDApp )
        
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"  # theme ( just know it by watching a youtube tutorial lol )
        
        self.main = Main()  # although it's a bit illegal ( not a right way to declare class variable )
        # but it works lol
        
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.main.update, 1/60)  # schedule interval to update
        
        return self.main
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyKivyMDApp().run()

    exit()
```

## Edit

For the `on_press` callback , seems like the MDList don’t have such method ( [KivyMD Documentation](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/list/index.html) ) maybe you can try `on_release` ?

and the project that I currently working on ( I know it's really messy lol ) ( just an example ) :

```
import datetime

from streamlit import caching
import gc

from goose3 import Goose
import webbrowser as web

import cv2

settings = """..."""

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, StringProperty

kv_file = """
#:kivy 2.0.0

<Main>:
    
    # background color
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: [0, 0, 0] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0.9, 0.9, 0.9]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            
            
    # bottom bar
    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgb: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [.25, .25, .25]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x - self.width /3 /2, 15 - 2.5
            size: self.width /3, 5
    
    
    # Screen
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        size: root.size
        
        
        Screen:
            name: "main"
            
            Label:
                id: main_center_label
                markup: True
                text: f"[ref=main_center_label]{root.main_center_label_text}[/ref]"
                font_size: root.font_size
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
                right: -(self.size[0])
                center_y: root.center_y
        
        
        Screen:
            name: "app"
            
            Button:
                id: clear_cache
                text: "Clear Cache"
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size[0] *1.5, self.texture_size[1] *1.5
                font_size: root.font_size
                
                on_release:
                    root.clear_cache()
                    
            GridLayout:
                id: app_grid_layout

                rows: 3
                cols: 3

                size_hint: .5, .5
                center: root.center
                spacing: 15, 15

                Button:
                    on_release:
                        app.open_settings()

                    background_color: 0, 0, 0

                    Image:
                        source: "sources/setting.png"
                        allow_stretch: True
                        center: self.parent.center
                        size: self.parent.size

                Button:
                    on_release:
                        root.ids.screen_manager.current = "bmi"

                    background_color: 0, 5, 0
                    
                    Image:
                        source: "sources/BMI.png"
                        allow_stretch: True
                        center: self.parent.center
                        size: self.parent.size

                Button:
                    on_release:
                        root.ids.screen_manager.current = "search"

                    background_color: 0, 2, 5
                    
                    Image:
                        source: 'sources/search.png'
                        allow_stretch: True
                        center: self.parent.center
                        size: self.parent.size
                
                Button:
                    on_release:
                        root.ids.screen_manager.current = "scan"

                    background_color: 0, 5, 5
                    
                    Image:
                        source: "sources/qrcode.png"
                        allow_stretch: True
                        center: self.parent.center
                        size: self.parent.size

                Button:
                    on_release:
                        root.ids.screen_manager.current = "timer"

                    background_color: 0, 0, 0

                    Image:
                        source: "sources/timer.png"
                        allow_stretch: True
                        center: self.parent.center
                        size: self.parent.size

                Button:
                    on_release:
                        root.ids.screen_manager.current = "reminder"

                    background_color: 3, 2.7, 0

                    Image:
                        source: "sources/reminder.png"
                        allow_stretch: True
                        center: self.parent.center
                        size: self.parent.size

                Button:
                    on_release:
                        root.ids.screen_manager.current = "device"

                    background_color: 5, 0.5, 5

                    Image:
                        source: "sources/device.png"
                        allow_stretch: True
                        center: self.parent.center
                        size: self.parent.size

                Button:
                    on_release:
                        root.ids.screen_manager.current = "file"

                    background_color: 0, 2.5, 5

                    Image:
                        source: "sources/file.png"
                        allow_stretch: True
                        center: self.parent.center
                        size: self.parent.size

                Button:
                    on_release:
                        root.ids.screen_manager.current = "screen_recorder"

                    background_color: 5, 1.5, 0

                    Image:
                        source: "sources/screenrecorder.png"
                        allow_stretch: True
                        center: self.parent.center
                        size: self.parent.size
    
        
        Screen:
            name: "bmi"
            
            Label:
                id: bmi_header
                text: "BMI Calculator"
                font_size: root.font_size * 1.5
                color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
            
            Label:
                id: bmi_mass_label
                text: "Mass : "
                font_size: root.font_size
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
                color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
            
            TextInput:
                id: bmi_mass_textinput
                hint_text: "In KG"
                size_hint: .3, None
                height: root.font_size * 2
                font_size: root.font_size
                write_tab: False
                multiline: False
                background_color: [.25, .25, .25] if root.theme == "Dark" else [.75, .75, .75]
                foreground_color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                cursor_color: self.foreground_color
            
            Label:
                id: bmi_height_label
                text: "Height : "
                font_size: root.font_size
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
                color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
            
            TextInput:
                id: bmi_height_textinput
                hint_text: "In CM"
                size_hint: .3, None
                height: root.font_size * 2
                font_size: root.font_size
                write_tab: False
                multiline: False
                background_color: [.25, .25, .25] if root.theme == "Dark" else [.75, .75, .75]
                foreground_color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                cursor_color: self.foreground_color
            
            Label:
                id: bmi_display_label
                text: "Your BMI : None"
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
                font_size: root.font_size
                color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                halign: "center"
            
            BoxLayout:
                id: bmi_info_boxlayout
                orientation: "vertical"
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: bmi_display_label.y - 15
                
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "horizontal"
                    
                    # left boxlayout --> info
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: "vertical"
                        
                        Label:
                            text: "Very Severely Underweight"
                            font_size: root.font_size
                            color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                            halign: "center"
                        
                        Label:
                            text: "Severely Underweight"
                            font_size: root.font_size
                            color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                            halign: "center"
                            
                        Label:
                            text: "Underweight"
                            font_size: root.font_size
                            color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                            halign: "center"
                            
                        Label:
                            text: "Normal ( Healthy Weight )"
                            font_size: root.font_size
                            color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                            halign: "center"
                            
                        Label:
                            text: "Overweight"
                            font_size: root.font_size
                            color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                            halign: "center"
                            
                        Label:
                            text: "Obese Class I ( Moderately obese )"
                            font_size: root.font_size
                            color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                            halign: "center"
                            
                        Label:
                            text: "Obese Class II ( Severely obese )"
                            font_size: root.font_size
                            color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                            halign: "center"
                            
                        Label:
                            text: "Obese Class III ( Very severely obese )"
                            font_size: root.font_size
                            color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                            halign: "center"
                    
                    # right boxlayout --> range
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: "vertical"
                        # size_hint_x: 0.3
                        
                        Label:
                            text: "<= 15"
                            font_size: root.font_size
                            color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                            halign: "center"
                            
                        Label:
                            text: "15 ~ 16"
                            font_size: root.font_size
                            color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                            halign: "center"
                            
                        Label:
                            text: "16 ~ 18.5"
                            font_size: root.font_size
                            color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                            halign: "center"
                            
                        Label:
                            text: "18.5 ~ 25"
                            font_size: root.font_size
                            color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                            halign: "center"
                            
                        Label:
                            text: "25 ~ 30"
                            font_size: root.font_size
                            color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                            halign: "center"
                            
                        Label:
                            text: "30 ~ 35"
                            font_size: root.font_size
                            color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                            halign: "center"
                            
                        Label:
                            text: "35 ~ 40"
                            font_size: root.font_size
                            color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                            halign: "center"
                            
                        Label:
                            text: ">= 40"
                            font_size: root.font_size
                            color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                            halign: "center"
                    
                Label:
                    text: "*** Just For Reference ***"
                    font_size: root.font_size
                    size_hint_y: 0.3
                    color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                    halign: "center"
                    valign: "middle"
                    
        
        Screen:
            name: "search"
            
            Label:
                id: search_header_label
                text: "Quick Search"
                font_size: root.font_size * 1.5
                color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
            
            Label:
                id: search_wiki_label
                text: "Search On Wikipedia : "
                font_size: root.font_size
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
                color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
            
            TextInput:
                id: search_wiki_textinput
                hint_text: "Keywords"
                size_hint: .3, None
                height: root.font_size * 2
                font_size: root.font_size
                multiline: False
                background_color: [.25, .25, .25] if root.theme == "Dark" else [.75, .75, .75]
                foreground_color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                cursor_color: self.foreground_color
            
            Label:
                id: search_web_label
                text: "Search On Browser : "
                font_size: root.font_size
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
                color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
            
            TextInput:
                id: search_web_textinput
                hint_text: "Search on Web . . ."
                size_hint: .3, None
                height: root.font_size * 2
                font_size: root.font_size
                multiline: False
                background_color: [.25, .25, .25] if root.theme == "Dark" else [.75, .75, .75]
                foreground_color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                cursor_color: self.foreground_color
                
            Label:
                id: search_wiki_url_display_label
                text: ""
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
                font_size: root.font_size
                markup: True
                color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
            
            TextInput:
                id: search_wiki_result_display_textinput
                text: ""
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: search_web_label.y - 50
                font_size: root.font_size
                background_color: [0, 0, 0] if root.theme == "Dark" else [1, 1, 1]
                foreground_color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                cursor_color: self.foreground_color
                readonly: True
                
        
        Screen:
            name: "scan"
            
            Label:
                id: scan_header_label
                text: "Auto Scan"
                font_size: root.font_size * 1.5
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
                color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]

            
            Image:
                id: scan_camera_display_image
                size_hint_y: .8
            
            Button:
                id: scan_change_camera_index_button
                text: "Current Camera Index Will Be Displayed Here"
                font_size: root.font_size
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size[0] + 20, self.texture_size[1] + 15
                background_color: 0.55, .55, .55
                
            
        Screen:
            name: "timer"
            
            Label:
                id: timer_header_label
                text: "Timer"
                font_size: root.font_size * 1.5
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
                color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
            
            
        Screen:
            name: "reminder"
            
            Label:
                id: reminder_header_label
                text: "Reminder"
                font_size: root.font_size * 1.5
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
                color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
            
            TextInput:
                id: reminder_input_item_textinput
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: root.font_size * 1.75
                hint_text: "Remind . . ."
                font_size: root.font_size
                multiline: False
                background_color: [.25, .25, .25] if root.theme == "Dark" else [.75, .75, .75]
                foreground_color: [1, 1, 1] if root.theme == "Dark" else [0, 0, 0]
                cursor_color: self.foreground_color
            
            MDRaisedButton:
                text: "This is a MDRaisedButton"
            
            
        Screen:
            name: "device"
            
            
        Screen:
            name: "file"
            
            
        Screen:
            name: "screen_recorder"
            
            
    # Always on display
    Label:
        id: date_label
        text: "____day XX _______"
        font_size: root.font_size
        size: self.texture_size
        x: 15
        y: root.height

    Label:
        id: time_label
        text: "XX : XX : XX __"
        font_size: root.font_size
        size: self.texture_size
        x: root.right - self.size[0] - 15
        y: root.height
    
    TextInput:
        id: main_textinput
        font_size: root.font_size
        size_hint: None, None
        width: root.width * 0.7
        height: root.font_size *2
        center_x: root.center_x
        top: 0
        border: 3, 3, 3, 3
        background_color: .3, .3, .3
        cursor_color: 1, 1, 1
        foreground_color: self.cursor_color
        multiline: False
"""
kivy.lang.Builder.load_string(kv_file)


class ScanQRCode:
    
    ...
    
    
class Search:
    
    ...


class BMI:
    
    ...
    
    
class Main(Widget):
    # font size
    font_size = NumericProperty(25)
    
    # theme
    theme = StringProperty("Dark")  # options : Dark, Light -> str
    
    # datetime
    now = str()
    
    # screen | main
    main_center_label_text = "Hello World !"
    
    # screen | scan
    camera_index = 0
    scan = ScanQRCode(camera_index)
            
            
    def clear_cache(self):
        ...
        
    
    def change_theme(self):
        ...
    
    
    def toggle_main_textinput(self, show: bool):
        ...

    
    def on_button_release(self, instance):
        
        ...
    
    
    def animation(self, obj, _center_pos, _duration, _mode):
        ...
    

    def update(self, dt):
        # datetime
        self.now = datetime.datetime.now()
        
        self.ids.date_label.text = self.now.strftime("%A %d %B")
        self.ids.time_label.text = self.now.strftime("%I : %M : %S  %p")
        
        ...

        # main textinput
        ...

        self.ids.main_textinput.bind(on_text_validate = self.on_textinput_text_validate)
        
        # screen | main
        if self.ids.screen_manager.current == "main":
    
            # center label
            ...
            self.ids.main_center_label.text = f"[ref=main_center_label]{self.main_center_label_text}[/ref]"

            if self.ids["main_center_label"].height > 150:
                _new_text = self.main_center_label_text.split("\n")
                self.ids.main_center_label = "\n".join(_new_text[-3:])
        
            self.ids["main_center_label"].bind(on_ref_press = self.on_label_ref_press)
        
        # screen | app
        if self.ids.screen_manager.current == "app":
            
            # grid layout
            self.ids.app_grid_layout.center = self.center
        
        # screen | bmi
        if self.ids.screen_manager.current == "bmi":
            
            # header
            self.ids.bmi_header.center = [self.center_x, self.height * 6 / 7]
            
            # mass label
            ...
            
            # height label
            ...
            
            # mass textinput
            ...
            
            # height textinput
            ...
            
            # display label
            ...
            
            if any(self.ids.bmi_mass_textinput.text) and any(self.ids.bmi_height_textinput.text):
                _mass = self.ids.bmi_mass_textinput.text  # kg
                _height = self.ids.bmi_height_textinput.text  # cm
                
                if _mass.isnumeric() and _height.isnumeric():
                    _bmi = BMI().get_bmi(float(_mass), float(_height) / 100)
                    self.ids.bmi_display_label.text = f"Your BMI : {_bmi}"
            
            # info boxlayout
            self.ids.bmi_info_boxlayout.top = self.ids.bmi_display_label.y - 15
        
        # screen | search
        if self.ids.screen_manager.current == "search":
            
            # header
            self.ids.search_header_label.center = [self.center_x, self.height * 6 / 7]
            
            # search wiki label
            self.ids.search_wiki_label.right = self.center_x
            self.ids.search_wiki_label.y = self.height * 5 / 7
            
            # search web label
            self.ids.search_web_label.right = self.center_x
            self.ids.search_web_label.y = self.height * 4 / 7
            
            # search wiki textinput
            self.ids.search_wiki_textinput.x = self.ids.search_wiki_label.right
            self.ids.search_wiki_textinput.center_y = self.ids.search_wiki_label.center_y
            
            self.ids.search_wiki_textinput.bind(on_text_validate = self.on_textinput_text_validate)
            self.ids.search_wiki_textinput.bind(focus = self.on_textinput_focus)
            
            # search web textinput
            ...

            self.ids.search_web_textinput.bind(on_text_validate = self.on_textinput_text_validate)
            self.ids.search_web_textinput.bind(focus = self.on_textinput_focus)
            
            # wiki url display label
            ...
            
            self.ids.search_wiki_url_display_label.bind(on_ref_press = self.on_label_ref_press)
        
        # screen | scan
        if self.ids.screen_manager.current == "scan":
            
            # header
            ...
            
            # change camera index button
            ...
            
            self.ids.scan_change_camera_index_button.bind(on_release = self.on_button_release)
            
            # camera display image
            self.ids.scan_camera_display_image.top = self.ids.scan_header_label.y
            
            if self.scan.get_data():
                self.scan.destroy_all_windows()
                self.ids.screen_manager.current = "app"
                Search().search_browser(self.scan.get_data())
                self.scan.clear_all_data()
            
            else:
                self.ids.scan_camera_display_image.texture = self.scan.decode_and_return_texture()
        
        # screen | timer
        if self.ids.screen_manager.current == "timer":
            
            # header
            ...
        
        # screen | reminder
        if self.ids.screen_manager.current == "reminder":
            
            # header
            ...
            
            # input item textinput
            ...
            

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        ...
                
        
    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        ...
            
            
class MyFirstApp(MDApp):
    key_pressed = set()
    
    # keyboard shortcut
    def on_key_down(self, modifier, keycode1, keycode2, keytext, keylist):
        ...
            
        
    def on_key_up(self, modifier, keycode1, keycode2):
        ...
    
    # settings
    def on_config_change(self, config, section, key, value):
        # todo : settings
        ...

        
    # build config
    def build_config(self, config):
        ...
        
    # build settings
    def build_settings(self, _settings):
        ...
    
    # build
    def build(self):
        self.title = "My First Kivy App"
        self.icon = ""
        self.use_kivy_settings = False
        
        self.main = Main()  ########## I did this to make it works ##########
        
        # settings
        ...
        
        # startup animation
        ...
        
        # keyboard key bind
        ...
        
        # screen manager
        self.main.ids.screen_manager.transition.direction = "up"
        
        # main update
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.main.update, 0.1)  ########## use clock to schedule interval the update function to update widget ( I do in this way )
        
        return self.main  ########## finally return the widget class ##########


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    MyFirstApp().run()
    
    exit()
```

// some code is omitted due to the word limit
// hope it helps : )